# Issue with sql join command

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two following tables,
first table: `tasktable` with following columns:

- projectid
- taskid
- user
- startdate
- totalduration
- remainingduration

And second table: `projecttable` with columns :

- projectid
- projectname

Now Im trying to query these two tables using join and get the all details of

```
taskid,user,projectname for the following condition

currentdate > startdate and remainingduration > 0
```

Can some help me in the query for achieving this condition.

Thanks

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Simply join both tables on `projectid`

```
select taskid,user,projectname  
from tasktable 
join projecttable on projecttable.projectid= tasktable.projectid 
where CURDATE() > startdate and remainingduration > 0
```

Hopefully the startdate column is dateformat

Answer (score 0):

This statement gives you the result that you want.

```
SELECT taskid, user, projectname FROM tasktable
INNER JOIN projecttable ON tasktable.projectid = projecttable.projectid
WHERE currentdate > startdate AND remainingduration > 0
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.taskid, t1.user, t2.projectname
from tasktable t1 join projecttable t2 ON (t1.projectid = t2.projectid)
where currentday > startdate and t1.remainingduration > 0
order by t1.taskid
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, thereby making it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM projecttable INNER JOIN tasktable ON 
tasktable.projectid = projecttable.projectid AND GETDATE() > startdate 
AND remainingduration > 0
```

You can add your condition inside join condition